# iOS app does not run properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, launch

I'm newbie in iOS development and I've got an issue with my app. I'm developing my first iOS app, everything is fine either when I deploy my app from mac on my devices. But the problem occurs when I wanted to start my app for example after week. I click on app icon and there is just launchscreen showing and app is closed. What should be wrong? It happened on many devices I've tried. My first view after launchscreen contain in viewDidLoad() function just these rows :

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loader.stopAnimating()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Now I don't know if I've got bug in my app or if there is some kind of restriction from apple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you paid for a full developer license, or are you just using your Apple ID?

Comment: I'm just using my Apple ID. So am I supposed to pay for full licence to avoid this problem?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to. Try going to Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management > <#AppleID#> > Then there may be a trust or verify button?

Comment: I think your observer is looking for the method when it's triggered out. Nothing related to developer program. it's related to incorrect code.

Comment: Hi, now I'm not able to find button you,ve described for me. But Paulw11 marked my answer as duplicate. He was right, it is duplicate but I have not noticed it. Guys was writing about apple restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check you have added `self.keyboardWillShow & self.keyboardWillHide` in your `ViewController.swift` file. Instead of `self.keyboardWillShow & self.keyboardWillHide` you should use `ViewController.keyboardWillShow & ViewController.keyboardWillHide with #selector`.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure that this will fix my issue, because everything works fine when I deploy app on devices. Issue occured after few days of deploying. But thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have return NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) line in deinit() as well.

Comment: As per Apple documents, we need to remove all observers in deinit() to completely remove observer from your app.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll handle it.